# Can I use arrow keys?

Tags: swype, input-methods, text-input

I've got a Samsung Galaxy Tab GT-I9100 running Android 2.3.5.

I love the "Swype" keyboard except I really want arrow keys. Is there please a way to add them or switch them on?

(Background)
I know I can tap the text entry box and a little pointer appears, but that's just not usable. Often, the vertical bar is always several characters off from where I drag the pointer to. If I want to insert text somewhere outside the visible area, its near impossible to get it to scroll to the right point.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The version of Swype pre-loaded on most Gingerbread Galaxy S's does have arrow keys built in.

Swipe your finger across from the <kbd>Swype</kbd> button in the bottom left corner of the keyboard to the <kbd>SYM</kbd> button alongside it, and you should see the cursor control screen instead.

[image]

[image]

Just tap the <kbd>ABC</kbd> button to get back to the normal keyboard.

*(the other useful extra keyboard you can get is a proper num pad by swiping from the <kbd>Swype</kbd> key to the <kbd>F</kbd> key in middle of the keyboard).*

Comment: +1 for another Swype feature I hadn't noticed.   Works on my Droid Bionic (2.3 Gingerbread) and Transformer Prime (4.0.3 ICS).

Comment: Yes yes yes! Thank you. Exactly what I was looking for without having to download anything new.

Comment: Really great...

Comment: As of today this still works but the "sym" key is now a "1234" key and pageUp, pageDn, Home, End have been removed. With Android in general, I wish there was a way to define my own keys more easily. Also I think the  Android volume rocker should switch keyboards. And rolling back to older versions (like Hacker's Keyboard allows) should be easier :-/

Answer (score 7):

Following keyboard apps have arrow keys:

- [Hacker's Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.pocketworkstation.pckeyboard)
- [Go Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jb.gokeyboard) with its [Pad Plugin](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jb.gokeyboard.plugin.pad)

Simply install them.

Hacker's Keyboard is not liked on smartphones due to its small buttons, but as you are on tablet, I'd recommend it to you. It has all keys found on a PC's physical keyboard (including even Control, Alt etc keys). Take a look of it:
[image: Hacker's Keyboard]

Use Go Keyboard if you want style. It supports more layouts, themes and languages. It supports swipe-based input, too.

Comment: Go Keyboard is my primary keyboard. But, when I use Connect Bot to access my remote servers, I switch to Hacker's Keyboard.

Comment: I love Hacker's keyboard especially because it does show arrow keys along side characters just like out normal PC keyboard. Other keyboard apps unnecessarily replaces character keyboard with arrow keyboard, so I need to jump between two different keyboards if I have to constantly use characters and arrows together. What now I am missing in Hacker keyboard is swype. *Is it possible to have swype on Hacker's keyboard?* Or *is there any other app which provides charachters+arrows+swype on same screen together?* Also *Go Pad plugin is not for phones so no way to get arrows with Go on phone?*

Comment: @PJBrunet You _can_ select text using shift + arrow keys using hacker's keyboard

Answer (score 0):

Current version of Swype (as of this writing) doesn't have the arrow keys feature.  I would suggest putting in a feature request on [Swype forums](http://forum.swype.com/forumdisplay.php?100-Swype-Dragon-Feature-Requests).

With that said, there are many alternative keyboard apps on the Google Play Store with the arrow keys built in.

Comment: Arrows are back in latest version. I'm using it now in Android 4.4.2